# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, typeerror

how to get list that looks like **likes** to **likes_clean**

```
likes = ['82.3k', '20k', '18.2k', '17.4k', '14.2k', '13.8k', '13k', '11.4k', '9.2k', 
 '8.7k', '8k', '7.1k', '6.8k', '5.7k', '5.2k', '4.9k', '4.8k', '4.6k', '4.6k', '4.6k', 
 '4.4k', '4.4k', '4.2k', '4k', '4k', '3.6k', '3.6k', '3.3k', '3.2k', '3k']

likes_clean = [82300,20000,18200,17400,14200,13800,13000,11400,9200,8700,8000,7100,6800,5700,5200,4900,4800,4600,4600,4600,4400,
 4400,4200,4000,4000,3600,3600,3300,3200,3000]

#This is what i tried

def likes_count(lks):
    lks = likes
    if lks[-1] == 'k':
      return int(float(lks[:-1]) * 1000)  
    return int(lks)
 
# i'm getting error when i try to call the function
likes_count(likes)
```

I'm getting **TypeError**: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

This is because int() is expecting only a string or a bytes-like object or a real number.

But you have put a list into the int(). It will not convert that list into a integer list as it converts strings to int.

You problem can be solved as below.

```
likes = ['82.3k', '20k', '18.2k', '17.4k', '14.2k', '13.8k', '13k', '11.4k', '9.2k', 
 '8.7k', '8k', '7.1k', '6.8k', '5.7k', '5.2k', '4.9k', '4.8k', '4.6k', '4.6k', '4.6k', 
 '4.4k', '4.4k', '4.2k', '4k', '4k', '3.6k', '3.6k', '3.3k', '3.2k', '3k']

likes_clean = [82300,20000,18200,17400,14200,13800,13000,11400,9200,8700,8000,7100,6800,5700,5200,4900,4800,4600,4600,4600,4400,
 4400,4200,4000,4000,3600,3600,3300,3200,3000]


def likes_count(lks):
    output=[]
    for like in lks:
        if(like[-1]=="k"):
            output.append(int(float(like[0:-1])*1000))
    return output
 

print(likes_count(likes))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[82300, 20000, 18200, 17400, 14200, 13800, 13000, 11400, 9200, 8700, 8000, 7100, 6800, 5700, 5200, 4900, 4800, 4600, 4600, 4600, 4400, 4400, 4200, 4000, 4000, 3600, 3600, 3300, 3200, 3000]
```

**There is one another problem that I have noticed.**

*You are assigning likes to lks in your **likes_count funtion** which is no use because likes list is the list you are passing as an argument when calling the method.*

*It means in the function it automatically gets the likes list and assign to lks variable. But again you assigning the same likes list to lks.*

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear.  The `int()` parameter isn't valid.  Use a list comprehension to process each individual entry, and the values are floats not integers:

```py
# added some non-k values for testing
likes = ['1','2','3','82.3k', '20k', '18.2k', '17.4k', '14.2k', '13.8k', '13k', '11.4k', '9.2k', 
 '8.7k', '8k', '7.1k', '6.8k', '5.7k', '5.2k', '4.9k', '4.8k', '4.6k', '4.6k', '4.6k', 
 '4.4k', '4.4k', '4.2k', '4k', '4k', '3.6k', '3.6k', '3.3k', '3.2k', '3k']

likes_clean = [1,2,3,82300,20000,18200,17400,14200,13800,13000,11400,9200,8700,8000,7100,6800,5700,5200,4900,4800,4600,4600,4600,4400,
 4400,4200,4000,4000,3600,3600,3300,3200,3000]

# items with k have possible floating point to be converted,
# but without k expected to be whole integers.
likes_processed = [int(float(x[:-1])*1000) if x.endswith('k') else int(x)
                   for x in likes]

print(likes_processed)
print(likes_processed == likes_clean)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 82300, 20000, 18200, 17400, 14200, 13800, 13000, 11400, 9200, 8700, 8000, 7100, 6800, 5700, 5200, 4900, 4800, 4600, 4600, 4600, 4400, 4400, 4200, 4000, 4000, 3600, 3600, 3300, 3200, 3000]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where you cast each `like` into a `float` and only cast into an `int` at the end after you have multiplied by a thousand:

```
likes = [
    '82.3k', '20k', '18.2k', '17.4k', '14.2k', '13.8k', '13k', '11.4k', '9.2k',
    '8.7k', '8k', '7.1k', '6.8k', '5.7k', '5.2k', '4.9k', '4.8k', '4.6k',
    '4.6k', '4.6k', '4.4k', '4.4k', '4.2k', '4k', '4k', '3.6k', '3.6k', '3.3k',
    '3.2k', '3k'
]
expected_likes_clean = [
    82300, 20000, 18200, 17400, 14200, 13800, 13000, 11400, 9200, 8700, 8000,
    7100, 6800, 5700, 5200, 4900, 4800, 4600, 4600, 4600, 4400, 4400, 4200,
    4000, 4000, 3600, 3600, 3300, 3200, 3000
]
likes_clean = [int(float(like[:-1]) * 1000) for like in likes]
print(f'{likes_clean = }')
print(f'{expected_likes_clean == likes_clean = }')
```

**Output:**

```
likes_clean = [82300, 20000, 18200, 17400, 14200, 13800, 13000, 11400, 9200, 8700, 8000, 7100, 6800, 5700, 5200, 4900, 4800, 4600, 4600, 4600, 4400, 4400, 4200, 4000, 4000, 3600, 3600, 3300, 3200, 3000]
expected_likes_clean == likes_clean = True
```